Apple thunderbolt 3 to thunderbolt 2 new adapter
Apple changed the model number of the thunderbolt 3 to thunderbolt 2 adapter. It happened this summer. It used to be MMEL2AM, while now it is MYH93AM.
Since Apple doesn’t call out any change, I’m wondering if anyone has documented the differences publicly.

Apple doesn't normally share those kinds of details. It could be an updated or different TB controller chip, or just an admin change. I'm sure it will still do the job.

If you have a specific problem other than being curious, feel free to edit that into the post. Asking “why Apple does things” is generally off topic, so making this about a practical question by may avoid close votes (which are reviewable and reversible should an edit respond any issues mentioned in the close process.)

I do not have any specific problem for now. I assume the main functionality of the adapter is guaranteed by Apple. However, since the change kind of matches with the advent of thunderbolt 4 and 5 and some other changes around Thunderbolt, I was wondering if the new one could have any “hidden” change that could pose an advantage or disadvantage.

Apple tech specs haven’t changed since March 2024, so you can be confident about which model you own or purchase. Apple warranty covers the product when you buy it, no matter if they are phasing in or out specific models of the same part.
See About the Apple Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter
